# Сжатие Bitmap в Android. Скорость работы

Tags: java, android, изображения, производительность, bitmap

У меня программа очень часто берет битмап и переводит его в массив байтов, следующим образом:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 5, bytes);
```

И потом я беру массив из `bytes`. Мне нужно как-то ускорить работу метода `compress`, подскажите пожалуйста как. Может есть какой-то еще способ перевести bitmap в массив байтов. Но дело в том, что я массив потом еще передаю через `Socket`, поэтому огромным он не должен быть.

И еще, этот битмап я получаю с `image`. Вот код:

```
Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * displayWidth;
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(displayWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride,
                                displayHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
```

По этому если кто-то знает, может сам экземпляр `Image` можно передать как-то, чтобы времени много не занимало, то скажите пожалуйста

Comment: попробуйте сжать байты gzipом или еще чем. Экземпляр при передаче у вас будет выглядеть как строка и не более. Поэтому только байты. Compress быстрее не придумаешь. Если у вас изображения килотонные, то тут думайте уже сами.